# Is it possible to dynamically set which permissions the next query should run with?

Tags: mysql

I'm making a system where any user should be able to run actual MySQL queries directly against a database. Obviously this opens for leagues and scores of security concerns, which I'm hoping to address using basic MySQL permissions. I want any user to be able to run SELECT queries against some tables, including joins. Other, logged-in users should have some additional privileges, including UPDATE and INSERT, for example. The permissions could also vary depending on user settings, environment variables etc.

To summarize, I wonder if it's possible to set up a bunch of permissions dynamically and run a query with those permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a set of users in your MySQL database, with the different set of permissions you need.
For instance:

```
User: NotLoggedIn
Permissions: select Table1


User: LoggedInNotValidated
Permissions: Select Table1, Table2


User: LoggedInValidated
Permissions: Select Table1, Table2, Table3. Update Table1, Table2, Table3
```

Then, when a user wants to perform an action, a select, you check if he's logged in and yes or no validated, and you use the correct user to connect to the DB, allowing this user no more actions than that schema( or db user) allows for.

Comment: Well yes, but this isn't as dynamic as I was talking about. I'd need a thousand MySQL users to cover all the combinations of permissions that I might require.

Comment: Well, you can indeed change the permissions for any user with the GRANT syntax: GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO user@'localhost'

Comment: I expect that's permanent though, not configurable on a per-connection basis?

Comment: That's permanent for that user, until you GRANT him other rights.

Comment: And that won't work well when 20 connections are using the user simultaneously

Comment: That's why using a predefined set of users with the correct rights would be a better way of working.

Comment: I quote myself: "Well yes, but this isn't as dynamic as I was talking about. I'd need a thousand MySQL users to cover all the combinations of permissions that I might require."